# How to read Junit configuration (ex.tag) inside the test method

Tags: java, junit

pom.xml -  i have the group which I like to read inside the test method.

```
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>${skipTests}</skipTests>
                    <trimStackTrace>false</trimStackTrace>
                     <groups>base</groups>
                </configuration>
```

java class, I would like to read pom value inside the Method if that is possible.

```
@Test   
@Tag()
    public void myTest() throws Exception {
     //read the tag value

     if (tag.equals("base"))
       //do something
     else
       //do this
    }
```

Comment: You can try to [define a system property](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/system-properties.html) and later on access it via `System.getProperty(...)` in your Java code, if that is an option

Comment: thank you so much for posting the answer. That worked for me. Follow up questions, any ideas on how to read ConfigurationParameter in junit test. Also do they have just property tag instead of system property since the value I am passing in is not related to system setting. just a string specific to test.